# insert/update in one query with multiple select with two values in each select

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, select, pdo

I need to know how to make a query like a title.

I have already this Insert/Update in one query...
But in this case, I have a form with multiple select which I need to Insert (or Update if the item is in database already).
To achieve this, I need two values for each select input:

- one for the id
- the other for the value

Here is the Insert/Update script:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO JUZGADOS
    (id, relacion2, opcion3)
    VALUES ";
    $insertQuery = array();
    $insertData = array();
    foreach ($_POST['opcion3'] as $i => $opcion3) {
        if (isset($_POST['delete']) && in_array($_POST['opcion3'][$i], $_POST['delete'])) {
            // Skip rows that are being deleted
            continue;
        }
        $insertQuery[] = '(?, ?, ?)';
        $insertData[] = $_POST['id'][$i] == '' ? null : $_POST['id'][$i];
        $insertData[] = $_POST['relacion2'];
        $insertData[] = $_POST['opcion3'][$i];
    }
    if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
        $sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
        $sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        relacion2 = VALUES (relacion2), opcion3 = VALUES (opcion3)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($insertData);
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['delete'])) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM JUZGADOS WHERE id IN (";
        $sql .= str_repeat("?, ", count($_POST['delete']) - 1);
        $sql .= "?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sel);
        $stmt->execute($_POST['delete']);
    }
    $conn->commit();
}
```

And for the multiple select, I have this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="opcion3[]" id="select5" multiple="multiple" required="required">
    <option value="Juzgado_de_lo_Civil" >Juzgado de lo Civil</option> 
    <option value="Juzgado_Primero_de_lo_Civil" >Juzgado Primero de lo Civil</option> 
<?php 
    include_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/config.php');
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, opcion3 FROM JUZGADOS WHERE relacion2 = ".$_GET['id']);
    $sql->execute();
    while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].|.$row['opcion3'].'" selected="selected">'.$row['opcion3'].'</option>';
    }
 ?>
</select>
```

On submit, the data is sent via ajax and I know how to explode and separate the two values.
I use this script:

```
    $result = $_POST['opcion3'];
    $result_explode = explode('|', $result);
    $result_explode[0];  //this is the id
    $result_explode[1];  //this is the value like: Juzgado X
```

**So my question is:**
How can I make the update in each select when the value (or the id) is already in database?
I don't want to save it again.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. Do you mean you want to check both `id` and `value` independently if they already exist, and update then? If that is what you are looking for: `on duplicate key` checks every unique key, so you have to add a unique key for just `value` (`id` is probably already your unique primary key). But you have to take care, it will not catch everything: if you have `1, value1, x` and `2, value2, y` in your database, and you send the update/insert `1, value2, z`, it will result in an error. (You might have to change your datamodel to prevent that).

Comment: Hi, I need to save the value in each select...there are already 30 items in the select, so in a case in the database are already per example 19 items and I need to save two more The problem I have is because this is a select and is multiple because that I don't know how make the on duplicate key update(the key here will be the id of each value in select).

Comment: You cannot combine `update`/`insert` and `select` in one command. You have to do two seperate queries (e.g. in your ajax controller). You can add multiple rows in `insert...on duplicate key...` like in your first code (though I think that is not your problem). If you just want to select exactly the rows you used/updates: you have the `id`s, you can use these to do a `select ... where id = $id1 or id = $id2 ...`. If you want to requery your original query, you can add the `relacion2`-Id (`$_GET['id']`) to you your option `valueoption value`. (Or I still didn't understand your problem.)